# Redirect old URLs to new domain (Spring 23 advanced domain)

Tags: mydomain, spring23

I received a message that informs that during Spring 23 the advanced domains will be deployed and that it is advisable to deploy them before oneself

So I enabled advanced domains manually

During manual activation, there was an option (Policy) that automatically redirects old URLs to the new domain

Do you know if after Spring 23 the old URLs will still be redirected or if I need to make any changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the enhanced domain feature released into the org, Redirection of previous My Domain URLs to our current My Domain will occur automatically  with out any setting.